# I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new PC and the Wi-Fi menu is not showing

Tags: wireless, menu

I can't see it at all in the menu and in settings it says no adapter detected

Before I got Ubuntu wi-fi was working on Windows 10 on the same PC

I have a NUC and this is my first time trying to get Ubuntu on my PC. Also I installed it from a USB drive

Comment: Kindly [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1322991/edit) your question and mention the details (manufacturer, model number, etc. ) of your PC.

Comment: Connect your PC to internet though LAN/USB tethering, and check if any additional drivers are available. https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: I have edited my post and added a 3rd paragraph to include more information

Comment: In a terminal window , `sudo lshw --class network`. Which model NUC (Intel's New Unit of Computing product line) do you have? Look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: When `sudo` asks for a password, type your login password.